# What changes should I make in my json url to get data of multiple countries and indicators?

Tags: json

I have got a json URL

"http://pearlinfosystems.com:90/home/GetIndicatorCountryData?countryId=14,30,37,44,83,87,109,119,249&startYear=1960&endYear=2012&indicatorId=1106"

I have countryId starting from 1 to 262 and indicatorId from 1 to 138. How will I change my URL such that data from all countries and indicators are available?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options when it comes to this kind of stuff, I'll provide two examples:

**Example 1:**

**Don't provide countryId and indicatorId**, meaning that you need to expect and URL in your webservice in this format:

"http://pearlinfosystems.com:90/home/GetIndicatorCountryData?startYear=1960&endYear=2012"

**Example 2:**

**Provide empty country and indicator Id's** and expect an URL with this format:

"http://pearlinfosystems.com:90/home/GetIndicatorCountryData?countryId=&startYear=1960&endYear=2012&indicatorId="

These are two options, now you just need evaluate if they fit your panorama.

Comment: I assumed that you made that WebService, if you did you'll have to make some changes in it so it accepts the examples above. If that WebService was made by someone else, I would advise you to contact whoever made it and ask for some documentation.

Comment: It was made by someone else

Comment: Then you need to ask he/she/them for documentation about the webservice